# How can I get multiple different cards to link to different modals using vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 6 different cards all that display different content. Each card has a read more button and when clicked a modal shows up. The modal needs to show the content of the correct card that was clicked. how can I go about doing this?

I have got the modal functionality to work, just need help getting the correct card and modal pair to link together

card code:

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="info">
    <h5>This is to test card 1</h5>
    <div class="button">
      <a id="open-modal" class="btn">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <div class="info">
    <h5>This is to test card 2</h5>
    <div class="button">
      <a id="open-modal" class="btn">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

modal code:

```html
<div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-box">
       <div class="modal-box__exit-button">
        <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke- 
      width="0" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="btn" height="1em" width="1em" 
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path
          d="M17.414 6.586c-.78-.781-2.048-.781-2.828 0l-2.586 2.586-2.586-2.586c-.78-.781-2.048-.781-2.828 0-.781.781-.781 2.047 0 2.828l2.585 2.586-2.585 2.586c-.781.781-.781 2.047 0 2.828.39.391.902.586 1.414.586s1.024-.195 1.414-.586l2.586-2.586 2.586 2.586c.39.391.902.586 1.414.586s1.024-.195 1.414-.586c.781-.781.781-2.047 0-2.828l-2.585-2.586 2.585-2.586c.781-.781.781-2.047 0-2.828z">
        </path>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h5>This is to test modal 1</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-box__contact-button">
      <a href="#" class="bottom-button">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-box">
       <div class="modal-box__exit-button">
        <svg stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke- 
      width="0" version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny"
        viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="btn" height="1em" width="1em" 
       xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path
          d="M17.414 6.586c-.78-.781-2.048-.781-2.828 0l-2.586 2.586-2.586-2.586c-.78-.781-2.048-.781-2.828 0-.781.781-.781 2.047 0 2.828l2.585 2.586-2.585 2.586c-.781.781-.781 2.047 0 2.828.39.391.902.586 1.414.586s1.024-.195 1.414-.586l2.586-2.586 2.586 2.586c.39.391.902.586 1.414.586s1.024-.195 1.414-.586c.781-.781.781-2.047 0-2.828l-2.585-2.586 2.585-2.586c.781-.781.781-2.047 0-2.828z">
        </path>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h5>This is to test modal 2</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-box__contact-button">
      <a href="#" class="bottom-button">Contact Us</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your current js code for modal opening. Probably there's an error in your event listener/ button binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can find them with custom data that connect with the element you clicked on

```js
function showModal(){
  alert(document.querySelectorAll("[data-target='"+this.id+"']")[0].innerText);
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var cards = document.getElementsByClassName('card');
  for(var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
      cards[i].addEventListener("click", showModal);
  }
});
```

```css
.d-none{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" id="1">One</div>
<div class="card" id="2">Two</div>
<div class="card" id="3">Three</div>
<div class="card" id="4">Four</div>
<div class="card" id="5">Five</div>
<div class="card" id="6">Six</div>

<div data-target="1" class="d-none">Description 1</div>
<div data-target="2" class="d-none">Description 2</div>
<div data-target="3" class="d-none">Description 3</div>
<div data-target="4" class="d-none">Description 4</div>
<div data-target="5" class="d-none">Description 5</div>
<div data-target="6" class="d-none">Description 6</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, guna add this to my local env now and see if it works

Comment: I tried your code snippet, however the modals still do not show the correct content in relation to the card that is clicked. If you need some more info pls let me know and i will share